# Failed to import pip modules on aws bitnami django lightsail instance

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail

i followed AWS tutorial for django lightsail instance: https://aws.amazon.com/es/getting-started/hands-on/deploy-python-application/

i tried to deploy my own code but apache gives me errors on piped installed modules.

It seems that instance have different paths. Some one has deployed custom django projects on django lightsail instance?

```
[Sun Aug 16 22:58:29.402644 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 4065] [client 177.240.102.67:65250] mod_wsgi (pid=4065): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/orderbot/ordermenu/wsgi.py'.
[Sun Aug 16 22:58:29.403437 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 4065] [client 177.240.102.67:65250] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sun Aug 16 22:58:29.403493 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 4065] [client 177.240.102.67:65250]   File "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/orderbot/ordermenu/wsgi.py", line 22, in <module>
[Sun Aug 16 22:58:29.403504 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 4065] [client 177.240.102.67:65250]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Sun Aug 16 22:58:29.403515 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 4065] [client 177.240.102.67:65250]   File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
[Sun Aug 16 22:58:29.403521 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 4065] [client 177.240.102.67:65250]     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
[Sun Aug 16 22:58:29.403530 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 4065] [client 177.240.102.67:65250]   File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
[Sun Aug 16 22:58:29.403535 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 4065] [client 177.240.102.67:65250]     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
[Sun Aug 16 22:58:29.403544 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 4065] [client 177.240.102.67:65250]   File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
[Sun Aug 16 22:58:29.403549 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 4065] [client 177.240.102.67:65250]     app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
[Sun Aug 16 22:58:29.403558 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 4065] [client 177.240.102.67:65250]   File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
[Sun Aug 16 22:58:29.403563 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 4065] [client 177.240.102.67:65250]     module = import_module(entry)
[Sun Aug 16 22:58:29.403571 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 4065] [client 177.240.102.67:65250]   File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
[Sun Aug 16 22:58:29.403578 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 4065] [client 177.240.102.67:65250]     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
[Sun Aug 16 22:58:29.403587 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 4065] [client 177.240.102.67:65250]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
[Sun Aug 16 22:58:29.403596 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 4065] [client 177.240.102.67:65250]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
[Sun Aug 16 22:58:29.403606 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 4065] [client 177.240.102.67:65250]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
[Sun Aug 16 22:58:29.403626 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 4065] [client 177.240.102.67:65250] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'phonenumber_field'
```

Comment: Have you installed `django-phonenumber-field`?

Comment: Yes, it is installed by pip. Even when i run the python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 command it runs, is just when i tried apache configuration that it failed to take the phonenumber module

Comment: Maybe when using Apache it executes under new python virtual environment, which does not have the package installed?

Comment: I think so, but i dont have idea how to link my pip modules to Apache. any thought?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that 'python install packages in a directory that apache do not see'.

so: packages get installed in '/home/bitnami/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/' and Apache looks in '/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/'.

The temporary solution I followed is copying packages to Apache eyes folder with this command 'cp -r /home/bitnami/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/* /opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/'

Answer (score 1):

I've the same problem, and for solve it, i made `sudo pip3 install xxx` and it's works.

Without the `sudo`, the package goes to `/home/bitnami/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/` and with it it goes to `/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/`. This directory is the one where Apache search.

Answer (score -1):

Just needed to use the root user with **sudo su** command for pip install packages, now are found by apache.